Prove $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x}{x-2}=1$ using the definition
I have to check whether $$\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x}{x-2}=1$$ or not,  using the $(\varepsilon - \delta) $ definition.
Because $x\to +\infty$, taken $\varepsilon>0$, I have to find $\delta>0$ such that if $x>\delta \Longrightarrow \left|\frac{x}{x-2}-1\right|<\varepsilon$.
Doing the calculation, I got that:
$$\left|\frac{x}{x-2}-1\right|=\left|\frac{2}{x-2}\right|=\frac{2}{|x-2|}<\varepsilon \Longrightarrow |x-2|>\frac{2}{\varepsilon}$$
Clearly, $x<2-\frac{2}{\varepsilon} \vee x>2+\frac{2}{\varepsilon}$ is a neighborhood of $+\infty$, but how can I choose $\delta$?
Then, I want to check if $\delta$ is good chosen:
$$\left|\frac{x}{x-2}-1\right|\leq \frac{|x|}{|x-2|}+1\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\cdot |x|+1$$
I want to deduce that $|x|<2-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, in order to conclude.
Can someone help me?

Uhm, choose $\delta = 2+2/\epsilon$? When $x \to +\infty$, I think the definition reads that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x>\delta$, some inequalities hold.

We generally don't use the letter $\delta$ in a limit $x\to+\infty,$ because $\delta$ is used in other limits because it is the start of "difference," while there is no such thing of the "radius" of a neighborhood of $+\infty.$ Since you are using the term "neighborhood" in such a limit, we'll likely need to know what that means in the definition you are using.

For me, a neighborhood of $+\infty$ is an interval of the type $(a,+\infty)$.
